# PayPal payment without redirection to PayPal's website

Tags: web, paypal

Is there any way to integrate PayPal without redirecting user to PayPal's website for payment in case of debit cards or PayPal payment type ?

Comment: For that you need to deploy Paypal as a product inside your application. As you do not want to use it as a service. And Paypal will charge very large amount for that. So better use this as a service as it is.

Comment: Could you please share a link for reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, it is explained by Paypal here : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-embeddedPayment-curl-etc/

Comment: It seems that this was canceled, quote from the page: "Important: Adaptive Payments is not available for new integrations. PayPal provides this documentation to support existing integrations."

Comment: The page has been removed. #404

Answer (score 2):

There are paypal products available in some countries with this functionalisty. I heard that Payflow Pro and Paypal Payments Advanced have such  functionality.

But actually from my developer experience, if Stripe platform is avaialble for country where your project is hosted, then better to use Stripe Elements - they found a way to securely place fancy controls to get CC info in a way your website can get just either a token or a payment method object, without redirects, and if necessary, show a popup with 3D secure window during payment flow.