# Silent payment using paypal without redirecting to paypal url

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal

Is there a way I can pass the sellers credentials to the Paypal API and it can make a transaction without taking him to Paypal URL?

TL. DR.
I am trying to build an eCommerce website for a shop with Paypal as the payment medium. The payment for user has been implemented where he is redirected to the Paypal website and he can purchase an item. But under certain conditions he is allowed to cancel his purchase and his payment must be credited back to him. 
I need this transaction to happen without navigating to the Paypal URL.The reason is that, the buyer is the one initiating the transaction. So there is no way he can authorize a transfer from sellers to buyers account. The buyer should be able to press the "Cancel Order" button and the payment should be immediately credited back to his paypal account.

I can store the sellers credentials in the server and send it to the API which should be able to authorize him but I was looking for an API which Paypal provides to make this happen.
My requirement is different from the anser provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520535/paypal-payment-without-redirection-to-paypals-website) question as here they still show a popup of paypal webpage.

Comment: The problem: if such an API call existed and wasn't limited to crediting a user's account, sellers could seriously abuse it, so I'm guessing Paypal hasn't implemented it in general.

Comment: @barrycarter I am not sure I understand the security concern. The code which raises the paypal request would have the necessary check to see if the buyer is authorized to cancel the order. Then we would be  sending the seller's login credentials to the paypal API anyway.

Comment: The usual way to handle this is to [let the customer approve a payment, but delay it's settling](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/authorize-and-capture-payments/) to the point of time when the transfer of the goods is finished. An approved, but not yet settled payment can easily be cancelled by an API call.